# Spring Data, MongoDB. How to get nested object (non-document) from document's array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, criteria

Mongo document 'History':

```java
@Document(collection = "histories")
@Data
public class History {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Transient
    private final String name = MAIN_FOLDER;
    private String appleId;
    private ArrayList<Item> historyItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Folder> historyFolders = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Model of Folder:

```java
@Data
public class Folder {
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private ArrayList<Item> historyItem = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Query with Criteria:

```java
    public Folder findFolderByName(final String name) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("historyFolders.name").is(name));
        return template.findOne(query, Folder.class);
    }
```

I got Null from this query. Sorry, I am new to this technologies, I did'nt find info about Criterias for documented arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the Query at the wrong collection.
`Folder` is not the collection but only a nested document in the "histories" collection.

And also: you cannot just return the nested document with 'classic' query execution. You have to filter it on the client side (your java code), use [projections $elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) filter and unwind on client-side or use aggregation pipelines for this. [Look at this Question: there are a lot of solutions if you need this in a query/pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection).

Your query looks correct. You only have to update your query execution to use the `History` Entity instead of the `Folder` entity.

```
public History findFolderByName(final String name) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("historyFolders.name").is(name));
    return template.findOne(query, History.class);
}
```

If you use this query often and there a lot of documents in your collection: think about creating an index on `historyFolders.name`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. The point is that if you write like this: `template.findOne(query, History.class);`, your `return` wait History, not Folder. I want to take Folder-model from this document

Comment: just updated the answer. Sorry i first did not see that you want the Folder and not the History model.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. But my idea is to get the "Item" itself, not the "History" with this item.

Comment: yes as you see in the updated answer: this is only possbile with client side filtering, filtering using projection and then unwinding client-side or with a aggregation pipepline. You can use all options with spring-data & mongodb.