# Join operation with mongodb using query criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, criteria

I have An Order POJO with a list of products as follows:

```
@Data
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Generated
    private String id;

    private String label;

    private Collection<Product> products;

    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    public Order(String label, List<Product> products, OrderStatus orderStatus) {
        this(null, label, products, orderStatus);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use filters on the order document, and I'm using query and criteria to do so.
It works just fine for the primitive fields, for example:

```
 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(orderField).in(valueList));


mongoTemplate.find(query,Order.class);
```

But now I'm trying to find all the orders containing a product with a given Id.
I guess what I'm trying to do is to perform join on the order collection and on the product collection so that a product matches the Id I want to filter by.
I know I can to it easily by using mongorepository, but I'm trying to find a way to do so with criteria.

Latter on I want to be able to perform 'and' and 'or' operation on my filters.

So I don't wanna mix mongoRepository with query and criteria filtering implementations.

I want through the [criteria java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html)
and these answer: [Spring Data, MongoDB. How to get nested object (non-document) from document's array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866973/spring-data-mongodb-how-to-get-nested-object-non-document-from-documents-ar)
and tried to to it like this:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("products.id").is(((OrderProductExpression) expression).getValueId()));
```

Any help would be very appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I figured it out- might be helpful for someone out there one day-

The problem was that I used @DBRef in my db schema.
Removed this annotation and it worked like a charm.